# How to join tables in two Firebird databases?

Tags: firebird, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

Currently I'm working on a simple library project using Embarcadero C++Builder 10.3 Community Edition, and Firebird and FlameRobin to create databases.

So far, I need only use simple queries, that were connected to a single database. Therefore, I used `TFDConnection` and `TFDPhysFbDriverLink` to connect to a `.fdb` file. Then, `TFDQuery` to create SQL commands and `TDataSource`. It works great.

Unfortunately, now I must join two tables. How do I write this command? I tried this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users_books 
join books on
users_books.id_book = books.id
```

where `users_books` and `books` are databases.

I got an error:

```
SQL error code = -204
Table unknown
BOOKS.
```

So I think I must connect somehow to these two databases simultaneously. How to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to join two tables in different databases? or two tables in the same database?

Comment: You can't use a `join` statement on databases, only on tables. See [Multi-database applications](https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/ufb-cs-multidb.html) and [Can I do multi-database or cross-database queries with Firebird?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq16/) in Firebird's documentation

Comment: @Roger Cigol Two table in different databases

Answer (score 0):

Firebird databases are isolated and don't know about other databases. As a result, it is not possible to join tables across databases with a normal `select` statement.

What you can do, is use PSQL (Procedural SQL), for example in an [`EXECUTE BLOCK`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-execblock). You can then use [`FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT ... ON EXTERNAL`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-psql-forexec) to loop over the table in the other database, and then 'manually' join the local table using [`FOR SELECT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-psql-forselect) (or vice versa).

For example (assuming a table `user_books` in the remote database, and a table `books` in the current database):

```sql
execute block
  returns (book_id integer, book_title varchar(100), username varchar(50))
as
begin
  for execute statement 'select book_id, username from user_books'
    on external 'users_books' /* may need AS USER and PASSWORD clause as well */
    into book_id, username do
  begin
    for select book_title from books where id = :book_id
      into book_title do
    begin
      suspend;
    end
  end
end
```